# Jetpack compose: elevate card from bottom

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-cardview, material-components-android

I was implementing `Card` shape in `Jetpack Compose` while I ran into this problem.

What I wanted was to only elevate one end or bottom of the card but I didn't find any relevant documents supporting that.
I tried looking into the implementation code of `Card` to get an idea (following is the code of the implementation):

```
@Composable
fun Surface(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(color),
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    elevation: Dp = 0.dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier,
        shape = shape,
        color = color,
        contentColor = contentColor,
        border = border,
        elevation = elevation,
        content = content,
        clickAndSemanticsModifier = Modifier
            .semantics(mergeDescendants = false) {}
            .pointerInput(Unit) { }
    )
}
```

but here it is accepting `elevation` in `Dp`, which means it with elevate the whole `Card`.

So I don't know how to implement it in `Jetpack Compose`, can someone help me with the implementation?

### Edit:

I created an issue for this question: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227767373

Comment: Shadow modifications are pretty limited so far, [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160665122) feature request is the most upvoted Compose issue

Answer (score 0):

You can elevate just the whole bottom like this

```
@Composable
fun BottomWithShadow(
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Box {
        Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                topEnd = 0.dp,
                topStart = 0.dp,
                bottomEnd = 0.dp,
                bottomStart = 0.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(50.dp)
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
            elevation = 10.dp
        ) {}
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(
                    RoundedCornerShape(
                        topEnd = 0.dp,
                        topStart = 0.dp,
                        bottomEnd = 0.dp,
                        bottomStart = 0.dp)
                )
                .background(color = Color.White),
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```